# Google Apps Script Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm trying to use the script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar) to populated a team calendar from individual calendars.

I can't get the colors to import on everyone's events.

Any suggestions on how to tweak the code to capture the colors of events, as well?

Thank You,

Jamie